# How to run multiple execlp() in C?

Tags: c, openssl, exec

I am trying to run multiple lines of openssl in linear order using execlp():

```
execlp("openssl","genrsa","-out","rsaprivatekey.pem","2048",(char*) 0);
printf("RSA private success");
execlp("openssl","rsa","-in","rsaprivatekey.pem","-pubout","-out","rsapublickey.pem",(char*) 0);
printf("RSA public success");
execlp("openssl","dgst","-sha1","-sign","rsaprivatekey.pem","-out","1.cipher","1",(char*) 0);
printf("SHA1 sign success");
execlp("openssl","dgst","-sha1","-verify","rsapublickey.pem","-signature","1.cipher","1",(char*) 0);
printf("SHA1 verify success");
```

In this case only the first line gets executed. I tried combining everything in one single execlp() and use && to separate the commands but still no results.
Can someone help me out of this?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that "execlp()" REPLACES your current program with the one you wish to "exec()".

SUGGESTIONS:
If you want your current program to persist (at least long enough to call multiple instances of "openssl", then use something like "system()" instead of "execlp".

Otherwise, consider using a shell script or .bat file to invoke the multiple commands, then "execlp" your script (with the appropriate "bash" or "cmd.exe") instead.

Comment: The standard pattern is a `fork(2)` followed by `exec(2)`, not `system(3)`, for spawning subprocesses.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated, the reason that only the first command is executed is that any member of the `exec()` family of functions never returns when it is successful - only on failure.

If you want the operations to be done sequentially, then using `system()` (as already advised) is the simplest mechanism.  If you wanted parallelism, or if you needed more control over I/O redirection, then you would need to build on the `fork()` mechanism.

Each time you call `fork()` successfully, it returns twice - once in the parent process, once in the child process.  These are otherwise very close to identical; the main difference is in the PID and PPID (process ID and parent PID).  In the child, `fork()` returns zero; you can therefore detect that your process should run the relevant command.  In the parent, `fork()` returns the PID of the new child process, which can be saved for later use with `wait()` or `waitpid()` and to indicate that the parent should continue with its work (for example, spawning more children for the other steps).